# Creando mi propio slider, pero con problemas de ejecución

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Buenas tardes y espero que estéis tod@s bien. Estoy en un proyecto nuevo y tengo que crear un slider con fechas, para mostrar la trayectoria del cliente. He utilizado como plantilla el slider de bootstrap 4 y desde ahí he comenzado a construir, pero solo he conseguido que funcione los botones de atras y siguiente y utilizar los dots que ahora son fechas.

La idea es que las fechas utilizarlas como los tipicos dots del slider, y según vayan bajando o subiendo salgan las fechas siguientes, teniendo en cuenta que va a ir desde 1996 al 2021, espero explicarme bien, además de que cuando cambie de fecha se me ponga el `activate` en el fecha en la que marco.

Esto que digo se puede hacer, tal como lo estoy construyendo?? Gracias.

```js
$('#atras').click(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');
});

$('#siguiente').click(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background: #212226;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #fff;
}
h1{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
h2{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
h3{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
h4{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
h5{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
h6{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}

.imgSlider {
height: 100vh;
-o-object-fit: cover;
object-fit: cover;
font-family: "object-fit: cover;";
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.barra-carrousel {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 19%;
}
.fechas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 101%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 99%;
}
.fechas .posicion {
    width: 70px;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
}
.posicion li {
    color: #fff!important;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.posicion li:hover {
    color: #EAE200!important;
}
.posicion .activate {
    color: #EAE200!important;
}
.indicatorsMios {
    padding: 0px;
}
.indicatorsMios li {
    list-style: none;
}
.activate:before {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #eae100;
    z-index: 1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -59%;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 7px;
}
.posBannerCareer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    width: 72%;
}
.posBannerCareer h2 {
    font-size: 8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.posBannerCareer p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    left: 36px;
}
.barraCareer {
    width: 20%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #eae100;
    position: relative;
    left: 9px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.myLife {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.posCareer {
    position: relative;
    top: -14%;
}
.sectionCareer {
    background: url(../images/career/CAREER-09.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0px;
}
.flechaCareer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 52px;
    bottom: 38px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
    
        <div class="barra-carrousel">
            <div class="fechas">
                <div class="center posicion">
                 <div>
                   <a id="atras"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                 </div>
                   <ol class="indicatorsMios">
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="activate">1996</li>
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">1997</li>
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">1998</li>
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3">1999</li>
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4">2000</li>
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5">2001</li>
                   </ol>
                <div>
                <a id="siguiente"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>           
    </div>
</div>
        


        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="imgSlider" src="https://images5.alphacoders.com/317/thumb-1920-317664.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <div class="posBannerCareer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="posCareer">
                            <h2>Career</h2>
                            <div class="barraCareer"></div>
                            <div class="myLife">My life in Formula One</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of.</p>
                        <p>type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged! It has survived not only five centuries industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="imgSlider" src="https://images5.alphacoders.com/317/thumb-1920-317664.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <div class="posBannerCareer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="posCareer">
                            <h2>Career</h2>
                            <div class="barraCareer"></div>
                            <div class="myLife">My life in Formula One2</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of.</p>
                        <p>type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged! It has survived not only five centuries industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En este caso he podido hacer funcionar las flechas de adelante y atras, incluso si le das a 1996 0 1997 me hace cambio de slider, las demás fechas no funcionan por que realmente no hay más slider, pero la idea es que la bola amarilla cambie al que esta activo, y por ejemplo solo mostrar 6 fechas en la barra y según le des adelante o atras, vayan apareciendo más o menos fechas, esto es posible?

Comment: La primera etiqueta no está cerrada correctamente. Cambiando las librerías parece querer comenzar a funcionar; cambia la versión de jQuery de 2.1.3 a una más reciente y busca los CDN de Bootstrap [aquí](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/legacy/bootstrap/)

Comment: Hola @Triby el fallo de CDN es al publicarlo aquí. En mi aplicación si funciona, pero no consigo que cambie el dot ni lo de las fechas, no se si me explico bien. Gracias!

Comment: Te sugiero comenzar de cero, es decir, crea el _slider_ siguiendo [el ejemplo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators), haz que funcione y solo entonces cambia estilo de los controles. Asegúrate de usar la mismas versiones Bootstrap de CSS y Javascript y quita (o remplaza) esa versión antigua de _jQuery_ `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Para los indicadores se usa una lista ordenada (OL) en vez de DIV y elementos de lista (LI) en vez de enlaces; desconozco si es requisito hacerlo así, pero conviene ir paso a paso, primero el funcionamiento y después adaptar el diseño.

Comment: Ok, @Triby probare como me dices! gracias!

Comment: Hola @Triby lo he cambiado por `ol` pero ni tan siquiera mi añade la clase activate al siguiente `li` no se como proseguir, lo pruebo todo pero sin éxito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No encontré cómo hacerlo funcionar de forma automática, pero la [documentación de Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events) menciona dos eventos que se pueden usar, para este caso, `slide.bs.carousel` se ejecuta al cambiar de elemento y devuelve el activo en la propiedad `relatedTarget` del evento.

Con base en esa propiedad, se puede obtener la [posición del elemento](https://api.jquery.com/index/) y usarla para activar el [correspondiente en la lista](https://api.jquery.com/eq/), eliminando primero la clase activa de todos los indicadores.

```js
$('#atras').click(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');
});

$('#siguiente').click(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
});

$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    // Obtener posición del elemento activo
    let index = $('#myCarousel .carousel-item').index($(e.relatedTarget));
    // Solo si hay un elemento válido
    if(index >= 0) {
        // Eliminar clase activa de indicadores
        $('.indicatorsMios li').removeClass('activate');
        // Activar elemento por índice
        $('.indicatorsMios li').eq(index).addClass('activate');
    }
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background: #212226;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #fff;
}
h1{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
h2{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
h3{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
h4{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
h5{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
h6{font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}

.imgSlider {
height: 100vh;
-o-object-fit: cover;
object-fit: cover;
font-family: "object-fit: cover;";
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.barra-carrousel {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 19%;
}
.fechas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 101%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 99%;
}
.fechas .posicion {
    width: 70px;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
}
.posicion li {
    color: #fff!important;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.posicion li:hover {
    color: #EAE200!important;
}
.posicion .activate {
    color: #EAE200!important;
}
.indicatorsMios {
    padding: 0px;
}
.indicatorsMios li {
    list-style: none;
}
.indicatorsMios li.activate:before {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #eae100;
    z-index: 1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -59%;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 7px;
}
.posBannerCareer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    width: 72%;
}
.posBannerCareer h2 {
    font-size: 8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.posBannerCareer p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    left: 36px;
}
.barraCareer {
    width: 20%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #eae100;
    position: relative;
    left: 9px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.myLife {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.posCareer {
    position: relative;
    top: -14%;
}
.sectionCareer {
    background: url(../images/career/CAREER-09.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0px;
}
.flechaCareer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 52px;
    bottom: 38px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
    
        <div class="barra-carrousel">
            <div class="fechas">
                <div class="center posicion">
                 <div>
                   <a id="atras"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                 </div>
                   <ol class="indicatorsMios">
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="activate">1996</li>
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">1997</li>
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">1998</li>
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3">1999</li>
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4">2000</li>
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5">2001</li>
                   </ol>
                <div>
                <a id="siguiente"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>           
    </div>
</div>
        


        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="imgSlider" src="https://images5.alphacoders.com/317/thumb-1920-317664.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <div class="posBannerCareer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="posCareer">
                            <h2>Career</h2>
                            <div class="barraCareer"></div>
                            <div class="myLife">My life in Formula One</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of.</p>
                        <p>type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged! It has survived not only five centuries industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="imgSlider" src="https://images5.alphacoders.com/317/thumb-1920-317664.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <div class="posBannerCareer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="posCareer">
                            <h2>Career</h2>
                            <div class="barraCareer"></div>
                            <div class="myLife">My life in Formula One2</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of.</p>
                        <p>type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged! It has survived not only five centuries industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección @Triby !!!! Eres un crack! Pero solo una pregunta, ¿ se puede hacer lo que decia en la pregunta? por ejemplo, si itero 20 fechas, solo mostrar en un unicio las 5 primeras y según vaya bando o subiendo muestro las siguientes fechas o las anteriores, según si voy hacia delante o hacia atrás.

Comment: @Miguel, sí se puede, pero tienes que darle altura fija al contenedor de fechas y modificar el scroll para que el elemento activo siempre esté visible. No había leído esa parte de la pregunta, voy a ver si tengo oportunidad de intentarlo.