# Timeline carrousel con personalizado

Tags: javascript, css

Buenas por fin el último carrousel de la web. Este en este caso es un timeline pero personalizado, he utilizado esta [librería](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) y este [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/Maxim22/pen/zQpvyg).

Os muestro el código:

```js
    /*** Timeline Carousel ***/
$('.desktop-owl.timeline').owlCarousel({
    loop: false,
    pagination: true,
    paginationNumbers: false,
    nav:true,
    center:false,
    margin:10,
    responsive:{
      0:{
        items:1
      },
      550: {
        items:2
      },
      900:{
        items:3
      },
      1000:{
        items:3
      }
    }
  });
  
  function matchTimelineHeight() {
    /* Add in the height placeholders for the images first */
    var imageHeights = [];
    $('.timeline-container .owl-carousel .owl-item img').each(function() {
      imageHeights.push($(this).height());
    });
    var tallest = Math.max.apply(null, imageHeights);
    $('.timeline-container .owl-carousel .owl-item .timeline-image').css("min-height", tallest);
  
    /* Now match heights with the placeholders added */
    var slideHeights = [];
    $('.timeline-container .owl-carousel .owl-item').each(function() {
      slideHeights.push($(this).height());
    });
    var tallest = Math.max.apply(null, slideHeights);
    $('.timeline-container .owl-carousel .owl-item').height(tallest);
    $('.timeline-container .owl-carousel .timeline-slide').css("min-height", tallest);
  }
matchTimelineHeight();
  
  /*** Newsfeed ***/
  $('.desktop-owl').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    pagination: true,
    paginationNumbers: false,
    nav:true,
    center: false,
    responsive:{
      0:{
        items:1
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.body {
margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background: #212226;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #fff;
}
.timeline-container {
    margin-top:30px;
    padding: 10px 80px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%
}
.timeline-container {
    margin-top:0px;
    border-top: 1px #eeeeee solid;
}


.owl-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    width: 89%;
    left: 83px;
}
/*owl carousel styles*/
.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot {
    background: #fff;
    border:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: #bfbfbf;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot.active {
    background:#417638;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
    display: block;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
}
.owl-stage-outer {
    top: -16px;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    position: relative;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-Y;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/*timeline slider styles*/
.timeline-slide {
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 2.2rem 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: inherit;
    position: relative;
}
.timeline-slide .circle {
    border: 4px #eae100 solid;
    background-color: #e0d806;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-redius: 50%;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 51.6%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    top: -33px;
    z-index: 2000;
    overflow: visible;
}
.timeline-copy {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: inherit;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #fff;
}
.timeline-slide .vertical-line {
    border-left: 1px #eeeeee solid;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2.5px;
    top: -18px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.timeline-slide .timeline-copy h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.timeline-slide .timeline-copy {
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
.timeline-slide .timeline-copy p {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    padding: 0px 17px;
}
.timeline-container {
  margin-top:20px;
  padding-top:6px;
}
.timeline-container .owl-stage {
    margin-left:18px;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #e6c996;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-dots {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:1em;
    display: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev {
   width: 55px;
    height: 36px;
    background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/font-awesome/1792/angle-left-512.png) no-repeat center;
    border: solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    left: -14px;
    background-size: cover;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next {
        width: 36px;
    height: 35px;
    background: url(https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/chevron-thin-right-1859438-1577834.png) no-repeat center;
    border: solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
}
.owl-prev span {
  display:none;
}
.owl-next span {
  display:none;
}
/* .owl-prev, .owl-next {
  
} */

button:focus {outline:0;}

@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  .timeline-slide {
    margin-top: 4.2rem;
    margin-left: 3.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<section class="normalDay opcidadNormaDay" id="modulNormal">

   <!-- <div class="barraNormal"></div>-->
   <div class="timeline-container">
        <div class="clearfix desktop-carousel desktop-owl timeline owl-carousel">
            <div class="timeline-slide">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="vertical-line"></div>
                <div class="timeline-copy">
                    <h3>09:00 - 13:00</h3>
                    <p>Preparatory phase with mobility and flexibility exercises, muscle pre-activation protocol and warm-up.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-slide">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="vertical-line"></div>
                <div class="timeline-copy">
                    <h3>13:00 - 16:00</h3>
                    <p>Preparatory phase with mobility and flexibility exercises, muscle pre-activation protocol and warm-up.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-slide">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="vertical-line"></div>
                <div class="timeline-copy">
                    <h3>16:00 - 18:00</h3>
                    <p>Preparatory phase with mobility and flexibility exercises, muscle pre-activation protocol and warm-up.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-slide">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="vertical-line"></div>
                <div class="timeline-copy">
                    <h3>16:00 - 18:00</h3>
                    <p>Preparatory phase with mobility and flexibility exercises, muscle pre-activation protocol and warm-up.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Para que os hagais una idea lo que busco es esto exactamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si os dais cuenta lo que hace marcar el que estás viendo (el circulo) sale en amarillo y los otros en grises, luego la unica caja de texto que se ve es la que estás viendo, las otras solo se ven la hora y la idea es conforme le des derecha o izquierda vaya moviendose y mostrando una caja y alrededor las horas.

Espero haberme explicado bien, es posible esto que digo de este modo??

Comment: y cual es el problema???

Comment: Que lo quiero dejar igual que el de la foto, los puntos no visibles en gris y los no activos sin borde, sin texto y solo mostrando la hora @FranciscoNúñez

Comment: y que has intentado???

Comment: He realizado varias pruebas pero sin una muestra de cambio, he conseguido dejarlo más o menos igual, pero supongo que hay que hacer con JavaScript y ahí ya me pierdo bastante

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, no necesito que me hagan la tarea, quiero aprender. Pero si necesito que me guie alguien que comprenda mejor que yo. Gracias @FranciscoNúñez

Comment: te acabo de dar una explicación de lo que debes aplicar al carucel; si al implementarlo te topas con algún otro problema gustosamente te poyaremos. saludos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta pregunta es muy similar a [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/447627/creando-mi-propio-slider-pero-con-problemas-de-ejecuci%c3%b3n) y la solución es prácticamente la misma, salvo por un par de excepciones:

- En la otra pregunta usas *Bootstrap Carousel* y en esta *Owl Carousel*, por lo que la captura de evento y detección de índice se debe adaptar. Referencia: [Owl Carousel Events](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html)
- Quieres mostrar más de un elemento en el espacio del Carousel y, resulta que este punto es el más importante, porque no hay forma de obtener el índice real, a menos que hagas que aparezca al centro, porque, sin centrar, los botones harán que el avance sea por "página" y no por elemento

En CSS hay que hacer algunas modificaciones:

- Poner el punto en color gris
- Ocultar el texto de cada elemento
- Agregar dos clases:

  - `.timeline-slide.active` para cambiar el color del punto al elemento activo
  - `.timeline-slide.active .timeline-copy p` para mostrar el texto del elemento activo

En HTML agrega la clase `active` al primer elemento.

En Javascript:

- Al inicializar el Carousel debes establecer la propiedad `center:true` para que el elemento activo quede centrado.
- Agrega una función para escuchar el evento `changed.owl.carousel` y cambiar ahí las clases para especificar el elemento activo.

Revisa los comentarios para más información.

```js
/*** Timeline Carousel ***/
$('.desktop-owl.timeline').owlCarousel({
    loop: false,
    pagination: true,
    paginationNumbers: false,
    nav:true,
    center:true,
    margin:10,
    responsive:{
      0:{
        items:1
      },
      550: {
        items:2
      },
      900:{
        items:3
      },
      1000:{
        items:3
      }
    }
  });

// La solución es igual a la de la otra pregunta
// Hice "copy/paste" y adapté
// Escucha el evento adecuado
$('.desktop-owl.timeline').on('changed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
    // Obtener posición del elemento activo
    let index = e.item.index;
    // Solo si hay un elemento válido
    if(index >= 0) {
        // Eliminar clase activa de indicadores
        $('.timeline-slide.active').removeClass('active');
        // Activar elemento por índice
        $('.timeline-slide').eq(index).addClass('active');
    }
});
  
function matchTimelineHeight() {
    /* Add in the height placeholders for the images first */
    var imageHeights = [];
    $('.timeline-container .owl-carousel .owl-item img').each(function() {
      imageHeights.push($(this).height());
    });
    var tallest = Math.max.apply(null, imageHeights);
    $('.timeline-container .owl-carousel .owl-item .timeline-image').css("min-height", tallest);
  
    /* Now match heights with the placeholders added */
    var slideHeights = [];
    $('.timeline-container .owl-carousel .owl-item').each(function() {
      slideHeights.push($(this).height());
    });
    var tallest = Math.max.apply(null, slideHeights);
    $('.timeline-container .owl-carousel .owl-item').height(tallest);
    $('.timeline-container .owl-carousel .timeline-slide').css("min-height", tallest);
  }
matchTimelineHeight();
  
  /*** Newsfeed ***/
  $('.desktop-owl').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    pagination: true,
    paginationNumbers: false,
    nav:true,
    center: false,
    responsive:{
      0:{
        items:1
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.body {
margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background: #212226;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #fff;
}
.timeline-container {
    margin-top:30px;
    padding: 10px 80px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%
}
.timeline-container {
    margin-top:0px;
    border-top: 1px #eeeeee solid;
}


.owl-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    width: 89%;
    left: 83px;
}
/*owl carousel styles*/
.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot {
    background: #fff;
    border:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: #bfbfbf;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot.active {
    background:#417638;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
    display: block;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
}
.owl-stage-outer {
    top: -16px;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    position: relative;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-Y;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/*timeline slider styles*/
.timeline-slide {
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 2.2rem 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: inherit;
    position: relative;
}
.timeline-slide .circle {
    border: 4px #ccc solid;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 51.6%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    top: -33px;
    z-index: 2000;
    overflow: visible;
}
.timeline-slide.active .circle {
    border: 4px #eae100 solid;
    background-color: #e0d806;
}
.timeline-copy {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: inherit;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #fff;
}
.timeline-slide .vertical-line {
    border-left: 1px #eeeeee solid;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2.5px;
    top: -18px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.timeline-slide .timeline-copy h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.timeline-slide .timeline-copy {
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
.timeline-slide .timeline-copy p {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    padding: 0px 17px;
}
.timeline-slide.active .timeline-copy p {
    display: block;
}
.timeline-container {
  margin-top:20px;
  padding-top:6px;
}
.timeline-container .owl-stage {
    margin-left:18px;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #e6c996;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-dots {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:1em;
    display: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev {
   width: 55px;
    height: 36px;
    background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/font-awesome/1792/angle-left-512.png) no-repeat center;
    border: solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    left: -14px;
    background-size: cover;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next {
        width: 36px;
    height: 35px;
    background: url(https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/chevron-thin-right-1859438-1577834.png) no-repeat center;
    border: solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
}
.owl-prev span {
  display:none;
}
.owl-next span {
  display:none;
}
/* .owl-prev, .owl-next {
  
} */

button:focus {outline:0;}

@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  .timeline-slide {
    margin-top: 4.2rem;
    margin-left: 3.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<section class="normalDay opcidadNormaDay" id="modulNormal">

   <!-- <div class="barraNormal"></div>-->
   <div class="timeline-container">
        <div class="clearfix desktop-carousel desktop-owl timeline owl-carousel">
            <div class="timeline-slide active">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="vertical-line"></div>
                <div class="timeline-copy">
                    <h3>09:00 - 13:00</h3>
                    <p>Preparatory phase with mobility and flexibility exercises, muscle pre-activation protocol and warm-up.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-slide">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="vertical-line"></div>
                <div class="timeline-copy">
                    <h3>13:00 - 16:00</h3>
                    <p>Preparatory phase with mobility and flexibility exercises, muscle pre-activation protocol and warm-up.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-slide">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="vertical-line"></div>
                <div class="timeline-copy">
                    <h3>16:00 - 18:00</h3>
                    <p>Preparatory phase with mobility and flexibility exercises, muscle pre-activation protocol and warm-up.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-slide">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="vertical-line"></div>
                <div class="timeline-copy">
                    <h3>16:00 - 18:00</h3>
                    <p>Preparatory phase with mobility and flexibility exercises, muscle pre-activation protocol and warm-up.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Nota:** Si no quieres que los elementos aparezcan centrados, habría que modificar el script para avanzar manualmente o, en su defecto, seguir las sugerencias propuestas en las otras respuestas.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Triby es brillante, funciona a la perfección! Si es cierto que tengo que dejarlo a la izquierda. Siento que varias preguntas sean iguales, no logro entender como funciona esto :D Gracias

Comment: @Miguel, a veces nos enfocamos tanto en lo que hacemos que no vemos cosas que a un par de ojos frescos les resultan evidentes, de hecho, leer las otras respuestas me ayudó a tener una mejor idea de que iba esto. Lamentablemente, no encontré la forma de hacerlo sin centrar los elementos.

Answer (score 4):

Mas bien pareciera que lo buscas hacer, es un timeline.

Dado que el carroussel no llega a lo que la imagen aproxima.
Cabe recordar, que no se hace código para otros, pero si se puede guiar en el sentido correcto para proceder.

Acá te dejo un ejemplo básico de timeline, que creo que sería más simple empezar por entender de como funciona esta parte. Y luego aplicarla al carroussel.

De todos modos, te dejo otra solución, para un carroussel con timeline:
https://codepen.io/hfavis/pen/JWzpXR

--- Edit:
Francisco igual me ha pasado un link, con un ejemplo más dinámico visualmente. Por favor checkealo -> https://codepen.io/vram1980/pen/jrzgXk/

```js
$(function(){
    var inputs = $('.input');
    var paras = $('.description-flex-container').find('p');
    inputs.click(function(){
        var t = $(this),
                ind = t.index(),
                matchedPara = paras.eq(ind);
        t.add(matchedPara).addClass('active');  inputs.not(t).add(paras.not(matchedPara)).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #424949;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  padding: 0 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  height: 38px;
  margin: 60px 0;
}
h1 span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.input-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.input {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.input:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.input::before, .input::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: black;
  width: 26.6666666667vw;
  height: 5px;
  max-width: 333.3333333333px;
}
.input::before {
  left: calc(-26.6666666667vw + 12.5px);
}
.input::after {
  right: calc(-26.6666666667vw + 12.5px);
}
.input.active {
  background-color: black;
}
.input.active::before {
  background-color: black;
}
.input.active::after {
  background-color: gray;
}
.input.active span {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.input.active span::before {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.input.active span::after {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.input.active ~ .input, .input.active ~ .input::before, .input.active ~ .input::after {
  background-color: gray;
}
.input span {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  visibility: hidden;
}
.input span::before, .input span::after {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
.input span::after {
  content: attr(data-year);
  top: 25px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 14px;
}
.input span::before {
  content: attr(data-info);
  top: -65px;
  width: 70px;
  transform: translateX(-5px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  font-size: 12px;
  text-indent: -10px;
}

.description-flex-container {
  width: 80vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.description-flex-container p {
  margin-top: 0;
  display: none;
}
.description-flex-container p.active {
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 1250px) {
  .input::before {
    left: -320.8333333333px;
  }

  .input::after {
    right: -320.8333333333px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 850px) {
  .input {
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
  }
  .input::before, .input::after {
    height: 3px;
  }
  .input::before {
    left: calc(-26.6666666667vw + 8.5px);
  }
  .input::after {
    right: calc(-26.6666666667vw + 8.5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-parent">
    <div class="input-flex-container">
        <div class="input">
            <span data-year="Descripcion1" data-info="Primero"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <span data-year="Descripcion2" data-info="Segundo"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input active">
            <span data-year="Descripcion3" data-info="Tercero"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description-flex-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @Excorpion pero el que estoy usando ya es un timeline, mirare los ejemplos que has puesto a ver si consigo editar el que tengo ya que en el snipet quizas no se ve todo como lo tengo. Gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Adelante!! el tema es ese, SI estás usando uno, pero no logra verse tu implementación correctamente. Entonces, difícil demostrar que SI estas usando correctamente el timeline. Fijate que el mio es un bosquejo, y funciona aun acá. La idea es esa, que llegues a tener uno funcional y ver que más necesitas.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que no tienes un problema especifico; simplemente lo que has hecho no tiene aun el alcance de lo que presentas en la imagen, y en tu ejemplo del sniped no logro ver que lo hayas intentado; entonces creo que a lo mejor necesitas orientacion sobre que conceptos aplicar.

Para que lo tengas te sugiero que apliques lo siguientes conceptos:

1. toma los elementos del carrusel y enuméralos comenzando desde 0.
2. a todos les colocas un display none y al circulito le pones el color gris.
3. cada ves que exista el evento del click para moverse a la derecha o izquierda validas en que posición del carrusel te encuentras y a ese elemento le quitas el display none y le remplazas el color del circulo.

En teoría te hace falta: investigar como se hace lo que te acabo de explicar y escribir código el código.

Si al implementarlo te topas con algún otro problema/error gustosamente te apoyaremos. saludos.